# cx_Freeze how to avoid packages getting installed in lib folder?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-freeze

When I build the installer and install the application, it installs all the packages in the `lib` folder whereas my code is picking the imports from current directory not `lib`.

How can I make the packages to be in the same directory as the executable?

Below is my script:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable 

buildOptions = dict(excludes = ["tkinter"], includes =["idna.idnadata"], optimize=1)

setup(name = "SoftwareGateway" , 
      version = "0.1" , 
      description = "" , 
      options =dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = [Executable("main.py", base = base)])
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, what you are asking for can't be done with `cx_Freeze 5.1.1` (the current version) or `5.1.0`.

You can use the previous stable version `cx_Freeze 5.0.2` which does not freeze the packages into a subdirectory `lib`. To downgrade to this `cx_Freeze` version, run

```
python -m pip install cx_Freeze==5.0.2
```

in a `cmd` terminal.

But I actually don't understand why it should be an insurmountable problem to have the packages frozen into a subdirectory `lib`, except for very particular cases. I would advise you to let your code pick the imports from the `lib` sudirectory by using the `__file__` property of packages instead of changing the `cx_Freeze` version.

Comment: Jpeg, Thanks for the help. The packages are developed by use and all the files imports from the local folder. If i have to import from lib then i need to modify entire   code base which is huge.

Comment: cx_Freeze 5.0.3 throws the error while running 'module' object has no attribute 'base_prefix'. This seems to be a known bug of cx_Freeze and couldn't find any solution.

Comment: @Sagar Good point (though you probably mean 5.0.2, not 5.0.3). If you really need this, you can manually patch your local `cx_Freeze` code as in [this commit](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/commit/6313a36df65e76d14fe82970d3b8199b3419c9ed) from the `cx_Freeze` repository.

Comment: @jpeg I'd like to respectfully disagree.  I read this post and installed `cx_Freeze 6.0b1` so to avoid freezing packages into the `lib` directory; however, this behaviour still exists.  Is there a flag or option I might be missing in `setup.py` to avoid this?  Thanks!

Comment: @S3DEV You are completely right, thank you. The difference between 5.1.1 and 6.0b1 with respect to the `lib` subdirectory concerns only (some of?) the DLLs required by the Python module and packages, not the Python modules and packages themselves. I've removed the wrong part from my answer.